# Yom tov sheni in Eretz Yisroel list

Tags: halacha, chagim-holidays

Does anyone have a list of the major positions  taken by poskim about Yom tov sheni for Bnei Chutz Laretz in Eretz Yisroel (e.g. [1] No recognition of YT sheni, [2] YT sheni kept exactly as in Chutz Lo'oretz in separate minyan, [3] some compromise) and the names of the poskim?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Jonathan Cohen has an excellent article and [chart](http://i0.wp.com/www.torahmusings.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/yomTov2.jpg) on Torahmusings.

The classical opinion is that you are defined by your home, therefore, the American visiting Israel keeps an absolutely full-fledged second day. The only caveat (based on the mishna in Pesachim about a visitor respecting the locals' practice) is not to offend the Israelis around you. Many (including the Mishna Brurah 496:13) would tell you to do your yomtov davening at home. For visiting Anglos to form a yomtov minyan is a public act that clashes with the prevailing practice, and Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt'l remarked that the walls of Jerusalem shed tears each time it happens! (Heard from a student of his student, Rabbi Neuwirth.)

The classical opinion is that of the Shulchan Aruch, Mishna Brurah, Aruch HaShulchan, R' Moshe Feinstein, R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, R' Ovadya Yosef, and Rabbi Mordechai Willig shlita.

The complete alternative is that you observe yomtov 100% following your surroundings. This is the Chacham Tzvi and, according to many, Chabad's approach.

Rabbi Cohen details the compromise opinions of Rabbi Hershel Schachter, Rabbi Shmuel Salant, Rabbi Aharon Lichtenstein, and Rabbi Joseph Dov Soloveichik.